# Is k8s.gcr.io/metrics-server-arm64:v0.3.6 the latest image available for arm64 deployments?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, arm64, metrics-server

Checking the latest image used in the metrics-server [Github repo](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/metrics-server/releases/tag/v0.5.0), the tag used is **v0.5.0**, for arm64 I would usually add *arm64* to the image name and pull it.

But the image doesn't exist and doing an inspect to the base image shows that its arch is *amd64*.

In [google's registry](https://console.cloud.google.com/gcr/images/google-containers/global/metrics-server) the latest image is `v0.3.6`. So I'm not sure if support for arm64 has continued or staled.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no need to append *arm64* starting v0.3.7, the image support multiple architectures. See official FAQ [here](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/metrics-server/blob/master/FAQ.md#how-to-run-metric-server-on-different-architecture) with complete image url.

Comment: Using the latest version without adding arm64 to the image name worked. The metrics-server pod is running fine. I was concerned because the output of the docker inspect command showed amd64. I think that that is the default value when one uses buildkit for building multiarch images.

Answer (score 1):

There are two tricks:

1. Please, check the [metrics-server/README.md](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/metrics-server/blob/master/charts/metrics-server/README.md).

Correct registry is `k8s.gcr.io`

```
image.repository    k8s.gcr.io/metrics-server/metrics-server
```

2. Seems there isn't `latest` tag in the registry.

So, `docker run --rm k8s.gcr.io/metrics-server/metrics-server` doesn't work.

But with version it works fine:

```
docker run --rm k8s.gcr.io/metrics-server/metrics-server:v0.5.0 --version
v.0.5.0
```